# TypeScriptでインデックスアクセス時のundefinedを回避したい

Tags: typescript

下記のコードで、オブジェクトは 'undefined' である可能性があります。ts(2532)
と、test[i].vの部分でエラーになってしまうのですが、原因がさっぱりわかりません。
コードの書き方で回避する方法はありますでしょうか？

```
// test.ts
type TestArray = {
  v: string;
}
let test: TestArray[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  if (test[i] && "1.1" == test[i].v) {
    console.log(test);
  }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。こんなにも多くの解決方法をご提示いただきありがとうございます。勉強させていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

（`tsconfig.json` などで `"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true` としていることを前提とします。そうでなければ、質問のエラーは出ないことでしょう）

[型の絞り込み (Narrowing)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) が行なわれる対象は変数です。`test[i]` のような式の型は絞り込めません。

#### 変数に代入する

よって、変数に代入してから扱うことが考えられます。

```js
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    // ここで代入
    const val = test[i]

    // 左でチェックしたので、右の val は 非undefined に絞り込まれる
    if (val && "1.1" == val.v) {
        console.log(val)
    }
}
```

#### オプショナルチェーン

[オプショナルチェーン](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) を使うとチェックがコンパクトに書け、TypeScript の型も問題ないです。

```js
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    // `test[i]?.v` の結果は undefined かも知れませんが、
    // この場合、"1.1" との比較で false になるので問題無いです。
    if ("1.1" == test[i]?.v) {
        console.log(test[i])
    }
}
```

#### 非 null アサーション演算子 (`!`)

`undefined` では無いことが確実であるならば、[非 null アサーション演算子 (Non-Null Assertion Operator)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) を使ってチェックを省略できます。

（自作のコードの場合は大丈夫でしょうが、JavaScript の世界ではプロパティーを読むだけで内容が変わるオブジェクトも存在しますので、コードのこの部分だけ見ても、確実なことは言えません）

```js
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    // test[i] は undefined では無いことを知っているので、
    // TypeScript に伝える。間違っていたら ランタイムエラー。
    if ("1.1" == test[i]!.v) {
        console.log(test[i])
    }
}
```

#### 別のループ方法

構文によっては自分でチェックする必要が無いです。

```js
// 「for of」ループ
for (const val of test) {
    if ("1.1" == val.v) {
        console.log(val)
    }
}

// forEach
test.forEach((val) => {
    if ("1.1" == val.v) {
        console.log(val)
    }
})
```